# Realm RLMArray as singleton?

Tags: swift, realm

I want to store RLMObjects in an array to keep their order. I need to save the array to resist the order of my objects. Is it possible to make a singleton RLMObject?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the following models?

```
@interface MyObject : RLMObject
// MyObject contents...
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(MyObject);

@interface MyDataStore : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<MyObject> *myOrderedObjects;
@end
```

You could make a singleton for `MyObject` and store your ordered `RLMObject`s in its array property.

Comment: I thought of this but it seemed cludgy to make a class, that you would only make one instance of, that only contained 1 property. Then again, considering that this class would really represent a record in a database, maybe it make sense.